# Javascript works in JFIDDLE but not HTML file

Tags: javascript, html

Why wont this code work?  It seems to only work on JFIDDLE..  Is there permissions or something?

```js
function loadData() {
  var url="https://docs.google.com/spreadsheet/pub?key=p_aHW5nOrj0VO2ZHTRRtqTQ&single=true&gid=0&range=A1&output=csv";
  xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
  xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if(xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status==200){
      document.getElementById("display").innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText;
    }
  };
  xmlhttp.open("GET",url,true);
  xmlhttp.send(null);
}
```

```html
<html>
  <body>
    <button type="button" onclick="loadData()">Load Spreadsheet Data</button>
    <div id="display"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Sigh. This isn't Java. It's *JavaScript*. The two are completely unrelated. How can this still be a thing in 2018?

Comment: Check out the `<script>` tag

Comment: when I put it in <script> tags nothing happens.  But if I use jfiddle it will show the results below the button

Comment: @JohnConde `new ScriptEngineManager().getEngineByName("js").eval("print('*Almost* completely unrelated')");`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like this:

```
<html>
  <body>
    <button type="button" onclick="loadData()">Load Spreadsheet Data</button>
    <div id="display"></div>
    <script>
        function loadData() {
          var url="https://docs.google.com/spreadsheet/pub?key=p_aHW5nOrj0VO2ZHTRRtqTQ&single=true&gid=0&range=A1&output=csv";
          xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
          xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
          if(xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status==200){
            document.getElementById("display").innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText;
          }
          };
          xmlhttp.open("GET",url,true);
          xmlhttp.send(null);
       }
    </script>


  </body>
</html>
```

This is a Javascript code not Java they are two different languages read this for more information https://www.makeuseof.com/tag/java-vs-javascript/

For Javascript, you would need to put the JS code inside a script tag like how I did above or as an external file.

Comment: Weird it works with JFIDDLE but not in my html file.  I know how to use script tag, just not surt why it wont work

Comment: Are you running it inside a server like Apache or something similar?

Comment: The reason I am asking is because I can't run the code by running the index I had to put it in a server to make it work due to cross-origin policy.

Comment: no just building the html file on my desktop

Comment: i dont know much about cross origin, is there a code workaround?  thanks so much!

Comment: it's not a code workaround you would need to install a program called xampp which is a program for creating different kinds of servers one of which is Apache which is what we are looking for. So, once you install it you would need to run it and next to apache click on start. Then copy your Html file from your desktop to C:\xampp\htdocs (delete whatever is in that folder first) then go to your browser and go to localhost which should bring up your file and it should work

Comment: This worked!! thanks.  now I just need to know how to make that html go live.  I assume local host can only be accessed by me?

Comment: I am glad to hear that please make sure to mark this as "answered" to close the question. Regarding the part where you want to make your html go live you can host it on a free server like 000webhost.com if you are expecting a small amount of traffic coming to it otherwise you might want to take a look at something like AWS but they do take more effort to set up. 000webhost is really simple and free which should be a good option for you.